# Data type conversion Error

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee

How can I change a date type value from input text field of a jsp form? I encountered an error while trying to getParameters:

```
 trip.setDepatureTime(Date.parseDate(request.getParameter("depatureDate")));
```

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Yes I accept your wish to solve your problem, but I think few people will take you seriously if you can't formulate your question enough well comprehensible. Maybe [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) quick checklist could help you to follow a grammar minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply no parseDate method in java.util.Date class. You can use `parse()` but it is also deprecated.

Use Java 8 LocalDate instead.